# MainActivity.java - errors on start

Tags: android, eclipse

mainactivity.java :

```
 package com.example.sdsdsd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

    @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
       }

      }
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

The problem is that is new generated project and everytime theres a problems telling:
R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: usually this is because an invalid resource prevents from generating the R.java. typically, in the posted code, the unclosed relative layout could be the issue.

Comment: There will be error in XML File so you should check it again..

Answer (score 1):

So I've found solution. I took other version of eclipse - Juno
The wrong version is Kepler 4.3
And problem could be of another reason - maybe I had Java 64 while my Kepler 32 bit. So if you're having similiar issue ceck your Java or try another vesion.
Solutions like clean project etc won't work

Answer (score 1):

update your java JDK,, and also update android sdk, then restart and try , must check for updating your android library

Answer (score 1):

Use **activitymain.xml** instead of **activity_main.xml** for MainActivity

> setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Problems console if there are any errors, resolve and rebuild the project or try clean and building the project.

Check if you have imported the correct R file. From your code it looks like you have not imported the R file.

Comment: yes - as I said R cannot be resolved to a variable. and i tried cleaning and rebuilding

Comment: give me more details how to do this. I've just started my first project in eclipse and there's an error

Comment: Just move your mouse around the R error and it will give you option to import the R file.

Comment: ok, helped in one case, thank you but now I have error main cannot be resolved or is not a field with getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); line

Comment: Can you please check in your gen folder ,if R.java file is generated.

Comment: If yes check if it has the enteries for your main and other resources..if you cant find reference it means ..your project has error ,may be your xml file..resolve that error than build the project

Answer (score 0):

Under `gen/com.your.domain` there must be `R.java` file, which is auto-generated. It won't be generated if there is any other error - in Java code or in XML.

So, your steps are:

1. Make sure you don't have any other errors.
2. Make sure you've imported `R.java` with `import com.your.domain.R` in the beginning of every file which uses resources from `R.java`. Eclipse has cool shortcut for it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, which organizes imports in the selected file.
3. Clean the project in Eclipse which will cause generation of `R.java`. Click `Project` > `Clean...`

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem in your xml files that  is actually stopping it to create R.java files. Please close the Relative layout tag you have in your .xml in the last. then clean the project. I hope it will generate the R.java and remove the error mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a 64 bit system, ensure that 32 bit libraries are installed. Run sudo apt-get install ia32-libs. Restart eclipse/ADT.